# Docker - mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, docker

When I tried to start **Mysql5.6** mirroring in **docker**, it didn't work...
The log says:
`mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2018-12-11 06:41:58 9 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.`

This is my command:
`docker run --name MYSQL5.6 -d a46c -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -p 3306:3306 --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci`
What should I do?
Help,please!Thanks!
[pirture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHY2s.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what image of mysql are you using, please share your `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### oh,It's my mistake!

I'm not familiar with docker's command rules!
The docker command line is order sensitive.
I should put `-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -p 3306:3306` in front of `-d IMAGE_ID`

Comment: More specifically, all options, including `-d`, need to go before the `IMAGE_ID`, so you could have moved everything right before `a46c` and it would have built successfully, also.